# Detect when scrollbar reaches top of div?

Tags: javascript, jquery, scroll, jquery-animate

I'm trying to animate a boxShadow on the scroll event of my #container div. Everything works except I can't figure out a good way to detect the scrollbar reaching the top so that the boxShadows can animate out. This is my code so far

```
   $('#container').scroll(
        function()
        {
            $('#white').animate(
            {
                boxShadow: "0 8px 8px -7px #696868"
            },
            "fast"); 
            if ($('#container').scrollTop() == 0)
            {
                $('#white').animate(
                {
                    boxShadow: "0 0 0 0 #696868"
                },
                "fast");
            }
        }
    );
```

I've added a demo. The initial on scroll animate works perfectly, but when the bar returns to top their is a rather long delay before the second animation kicks in. http://jsfiddle.net/JYqC3/14/

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Hope this helps

Used **[.scrollTop](http://jqapi.com/#p=scrollTop)**

```
$('#my_div').scroll(function() {
    var pos = $('#my_div').scrollTop();
    if (pos == 0) {
        alert('top of the div');
    }
});
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/dhirajbodicherla/JYqC3/)**

**EDIT:** better animation added to demo

Comment: Thanks for your answer. This is basically what I have written, if I were to put an alert in my if statement it would fire off right when the bar hits the top. For some reason there is a long delay for the animation to kick in in the if statement.

Comment: here i edited the jsfiddle. Scroll down and see the shadow instantly appear, but when you scroll to the top you have to wait like 5 seconds before it disappears. I am using a jquery plugin which is included in the top of the html http://jsfiddle.net/JYqC3/12/

Comment: updated my demo, its definitely not the best soln, i had no time, so made a temp fix

Comment: thanks a lot, but if a user were to scroll fast then it doesn't catch, but you probably already knew that.

Comment: Do you know why any of these implementations don't work when you click the bar and drag to scroll?

Comment: wow that works perfectly! Thank you so much! If you have any time could you please explain how it works? I'm not sure what the queue function does.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/10650/discussion-between-dhiraj-bodicherla-and-wilfred)

Comment: hey there, I updated my answer with a better solution, hope it helps you