# How to know the scrollbar reached top of the component in reactjs

Tags: reactjs

I have got Component with scroll bar inside it. I would like to know when the scroll bar reaches the top of the component.

Please if anybody can guide me...

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Detect when scrollbar reaches top of div?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10344211/detect-when-scrollbar-reaches-top-of-div)

Answer (score 0):

Created an example for you on [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/wizardly-ramanujan-y6x01d?file=/src/App.js)

Simplified example:

```
function Component() {
  const ref = useRef(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    const element = ref.current;
    const handleScroll = (e) => {
      if (element.scrollTop === 0) {
        console.log("do something");
        // do whatever you want here
      }
    };
    element.addEventListener("scroll", handleScroll);
    return () => element.removeEventListener("scroll", handleScroll);
  }, []);

  return (
    <div ref={ref}></div>
  );
}
```

You can also make a hook out of it if you want to.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `scroll` event. No need for `ref`.

```
class MyComponent extends React.Component {

    handleScroll=(evt)=> { // use this of object instance
        if(!evt.currentTarget.scrollTop) {

        }
    }  

    render() {
        return '<div onScroll={this.handleScroll}></div>';
    }

}
```